# Stimulsoft Designer. Databind inside another databind

Tags: stimulsoft

In stimulsoft, I have an SQL query that displays information about an animal in the "Data" component on each page. I want to add another data source that takes the Animal Id and displays a list of its events on this page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Master-Detail report.
Add one more data band and set its properties:

- Master Component
- Relation